# Change the password of the "system" user in Oracle12c database using sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl, oracle12c

I wan to change the password of the "system" user using sql developer but I get the following error when I run this command

I create a connection using the system user and run the following command

```
    alter user system identified by "myPass" replace "myPass" CONTAINER=ALL ;
```

this is the error that I get

```
Error SQL: ORA-65050: Las DDL comunes solo se permiten en CDB$ROOT
65050. 00000 -  "Common DDLs only allowed in CDB$ROOT"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to issue a Common DDL in a pluggable database.
*Action:   Switch to CDB$ROOT and issue the Common DDL there.
Confirmación terminada.
```

it says that I need to switch to `CDB$ROOT` but I don't know what that is and how to switch to that mode using sql developer

Comment: there's two databases here, a container db, that has things common to all of the databases running in it - like USERS such as SYSTEM, and the database that you're connected to, which is a PLUGGABLE database. You need to find the SERVICE or SID of the container, and CONNECT to it in sql developer, then you can change that user's password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is very clear: `Switch to CDB$ROOT` - there is nothing confusing about that.

You don't know how?

```
alter session set container = cdb$root
```

Comment: and once you're there as SYSTEM, you can do very bad things - so don't go there until you understand the purpose of the CDB

Comment: If he needs to change the SYSTEM password, there is no other choice. As to doing bad things - I will venture to guess that the OP, like me, is working on a learning sandbox, not on an actual DB of any importance, so the chance for causing a true disaster is probably low.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but leave the attitude home.

Comment: @Mieszko - You are welcome. As for your other comment - I *am* at home, so I guess we're good?

Comment: I won't dignify it with a comment.